# Quick way to check multiple similar elements within list of arrays Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is an efficient way to detect similar elements in a list of arrays, where the element(s) can be in the same array or a different array?

I'm representing a matrix as a grid of blocks, and any element with the same value that stands next to each other is combined into one "block". The blocks can be rectangular or square, but cannot be L-shaped. I also need to keep track of how many elements there are.

For example, the arrays can be like these:

```
[[1, 2, 2, 1, 4]
,[3, 4, 0, 1, 0]]
```

And the "blocks" here would be one block of 2 and one block of 1

```
[[0, 2, 2, 0, 3]
,[3, 2, 2, 1, 4]]
```

The "block" here would be one block of 2

The syntax `for element in list` and `list(set(list1).intersection(list2))` do not give you how many elements there are, and I can try to use a bunch of for loops, but is there a better way to do this?

**UPDATE**: The block length is 2 maximum (2 horizontal and 2 vertical like example 2).

```
x = 0
for row in grid: # loop each array in grid of arrays
   y = 0
   for val in row: # loop each value in array
      if val == row[y + 1]: # found horizontal block of 2 (same block on the right)
         # DO SOMETHING
      elif val == self.state[x + 1][y]: # found vertical block of 2 (same block on the bottom)
         # DO SOMETHING
      elif val == row[y - 1] or 
           val == self.state[x - 1][y]: # block already checked in previous if
         continue; # skip loop
      else: # stand alone block 
         # DO SOMETHING

      y += 1;
   x += 1;
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Do you have a working solution that isn't fast enough?

Comment: @blakev I updated my code

Comment: Are you open to using NumPy? Or must you use the list-of-lists representation?

Comment: @bnaecker I never used NumPy so I went with this implementation, but as long as I can represent a 2D array, everything is okay

Comment: Look into using `np.diff`, which computes differences along a given axis. You can use this to find the blocks entirely within one axis, but will have to do a bit more work to get the square-sized blocks. But this solution will be vectorized, and so fast and efficient.